# How to maintain Suntour XCR Air RL-R (remote lockout air/oil) front fork?

Tags: maintenance, fork, suspension, full-suspension

My bike is fairly new (1000 km) however I am worried about accumulation of dirt/scratches on the front fork.

I've looked at Suntour foam rings however could not find anything.

Is this because Suntours do not require maintenance like FOX / Rockshox or is there another reason?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any half-decent fork requires maintenance, the air variety of XCR not being an exception. True, Suntour does not seem to publish XCR-specific docs compared to other higher priced forks like Auron or Axon, but there's a [general fork manual available](http://www.srsuntour-cycling.com/fileadmin/user_upload/Downloads/Consumer/Bike/Owners%20manuals/2014/general-fork-manual-english-web.pdf). Some relevant quotes from it:

> **MAINTENANCE PLAN**
>
> **after every ride:** Clean the fork tubes and dust seals and maintain with an oily cloth / check stanchion tubes for scratches
>
> **every 50 hours:** Maintenance 1 (at dealer)
>
> **every 100 hours or once a year:** Maintenance 2 (at dealer, ideally before winter time in order to protect all parts from the effects of weather by proper greasing)
>
> **MAINTENANCE 1:**
>
> Check function of fork / check torques of mountings screws and nuts at dropout (10 Nm) / check
>   for scratches, dents, cracks, discolouration, signs of wear and signs of minor corrosion (maintain
>   with oily cloth).
>
> **MAINTENANCE 2:**
>
> Maintenance 1 + disassembly / cleaning the entire fork inside and out / cleaning and lubricating
>   dust seals and slider sleeves / checking torques / adjusting to the riders liking.
>   Before disassembly, check the slider sleeve play of the fork. To do so, apply the front wheel
>   brake and gently push the bicycle back and forth at the handlebar stem shaft. Replace the slider
>   sleeves if the play is too big (more than 1 mm at the fork brace).

I'd advise to contact the venue you bought the bike from and even SR Suntour itself for further details.

Comment: This is fantastic, thank you! I bought the bicycle overseas as it is not sold in my country so the maintenance in on my part - I am quite mechanical so should be fine :)

Comment: One follow up, I assume that "maintain with oily cloth" means to oil it when it's cleaned but wipe it off prior to the next ride so that no dirt sticks to it?

Comment: I wouldn't go as far as "oil it when it's cleaned", that part's not very clear to me either. Personally, I just wipe stanchions clean with a regular rag before/after every ride.